# При hover изменение контентной области

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, border

```
.link:hover {
    width: auto;
    height: 18px;
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

При hover контентная часть (та которая выделяеться цветом black) по размеру не соответсвует размерам самой кнопки.
Как исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Может быть: 
box-sizing:border-box
Но лучше, прикрепите ссылку на пример

Comment: box-sizing:border-box задан для самого класса .link.

Comment: может там что-то мешает

Comment: Давайте же пример уже

Comment: подскажите, как вставить скриншот сюда? сорри, но не вкурсе( хочу просто наглядно показать, как все выглядит

Comment: Скриншот без кода, не очень поможет.
Используйте https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, можно исправить свойством `box-sizing:border-box`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Это не так. https://jsfiddle.net/cu9oevx7/

Answer (score 0):

Проблема разрешится через общего стиля для кнопки И кнопки с псевдоклассом hover:

`.link, .link:hover {
    height: 18px;
}`

При это использование свойства `box-sizing` факультативно, но так можно добавить в этот же селектор.